# What is the meaning of phone conversation between Lee and Ron?

Tags: plot-explanation, money-monster

In **[Money Monster](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt2241351/)**, ***Ron*** is in a toilet room and ***Lee*** is backstage of the "**Money Monsters**" show, but they had this phone conversation:

> Lee: Hang on, Patty. Just one second. Ron, you walking hard or what?
>
> Ron: **This stuff is incredible. I'm talking zero to 60 in, like, 20
>   seconds flat.**
>
> Lee: **Good, so it's a buy, then.**
>   All right. Put it away and find me a better lead for next week's show.

Comment: Without context it's unclear how this conversation proceded...they just isn't enough information here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The context of the scene is that Ron is testing a medicine for erectile dysfunction.

Lee wants to know if it works so he can recommend the stock.

Ron is saying he got an erection in 20 seconds flat.

Lee is responding that it sounds like he should recommend people buy the stock then.

Answer (score 0):

With the placement of him (toilet room) and the intimation that he is breathing heavily ('walking hard') - it sounds like Ron' has just taken some cocaine. Which has given him a boost (making a simile that it is similar to a car going from Zero to sixty miles an hour in 2 seconds)

Given that 'Lee' tells 'Ron'to "put it away" and "find [him] a better lead", it also sounds like they are in the entertainment industry, which is allegedly rife with cocaine use.

But, as mentioned above, without context it's hard to tell for certain.